# Why is ChartJS not working on Windows 10 machines? (Works fine on MacOS)

Tags: javascript, php, windows-10, chart.js

I created some charts using ChartJS for a project, pushed the changes to GitHub, and now it only seems to work for me and 1 other person on my team (Who is also using a mac). The charts don't appear for anyone else (everyone else is using a Windows 10 machine).

Any idea what might be causing this? Anything I can do to get around this issue?

Comment: What browser (Edge, IE)? Any browser console errors? Any other config details not provided in the question? Might also try to clear browser cache in case something might be 'quirky'.

Comment: Ask someone to give a look into their browser console on win10 and post messages here